# Use default values for some props without having to specify every single one in the FC arguments?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

With defaultProps being [deprecated](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1133878326358171650), I wonder if it is possible to only declare *some* props' default values in the function arguments and not having to specify *every* prop in the arguments , as soon as one is supposed to have a default value.

```
interface AutocompleteInputProps {
    items: any[],
    key: string,
    searchIcon?: boolean,
    clearSearchIcon?: boolean
}

export const AutocompleteInput: React.FC<AutocompleteInputProps> = ({ searchIcon = true, items = [], key = 'name', clearSearchIcon = true }: AutocompleteInputProps) => {    
    return (
        <></>
  )      
}
```

Here I only want default values for the two booleans, however since I am specifying values for them in the FC arguments, I must also include the other possible props with them, which get's a little iffy for some of my components that have a lot of optional or inherited props

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the [rest property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property) which will collect the rest of the props:

```
export const AutocompleteInput: React.FC<AutocompleteInputProps> = ({ searchIcon = true, clearSearchIcon = true, ...restProps }: AutocompleteInputProps) => {
    // If you need access to the other props later
    const { items, key } = restProps;
    return (
        <></>
  )      
}
```